# Refresh to show new/random taxonomy

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, random

I have an area on my Wordpress theme where I am showing info about a random taxonomy. Basically, the taxonomy is "playwrights" and I am featuring a random one on the home page. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="home-top-right">
    <?php
    $allpw = get_terms( 'playwrights', 'hide_empty=0' );
    $randpw = $allpw[ array_rand( $allpw ) ];
    $randpw = get_term($randpw->term_id, 'playwrights');
    $pwlink = get_term_link($randpw->term_id, 'playwrights');
    ?>

    <div class="title">
    Playwright Spotlight
    <li class="fa fa-refresh refresh"></li>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="p-spotlight">
        <?php if (get_field('image', 'playwrights_'.$randpw->term_id)) { ?>
        <div class="thumb">
            <?php $imageid = get_field('image', 'playwrights_'.$randpw->term_id); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $pwlink; ?>">
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($imageid, 'pwthumb'); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="text">
            <div class="sub-title">
            <a href="<?php echo $pwlink; ?>"><?php echo $randpw->name; ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php echo print_excerpt('', '200'); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to click a button (in the code, it is the `<i>` tag) and reload just that section (not the whole page) with a new random taxonomy term (playwright). I'm not great at JS/jquery and I'm not able to find a tutorial online that gets me where I need to go, especially considering the exchange between post data and the js function.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress has an admin-ajax.php file which you can send AJAX calls to. You can create a hook that is linked to your own custom function in which you can do the stuff you want, like getting the random term and send it back to the client.
Then you can pass a value to your AJAX call, called 'action'. When admin-ajax.php is getting a POST request with the action you 'hooked', your custom function is being executed.

Have a look at the links below for a more detailed explanation:

1. http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-ajax-with-php-on-your-wp-site-without-a-plugin/
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a good starting point. If I'm successful at completing the project, I'll post back with a code example.